# Nmap scanning Virtualbox Windows VM through static IP

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, nmap

I have a Windows 7 VM set up on a Ubuntu host with a static IP assigned to the VM (192.168.56.2) but when I tried scanning this IP with nmap I got strange results

```
root@Host-PC:~# nmap 192.168.56.2

Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-23 20:04 EEST
Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.2
Host is up (0.00061s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.56.2 are filtered
MAC Address: 08:00:27:E5:2A:3E (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 21.40 seconds
```

while doing the same scan from the Windows guest yields

```
nmap 192.168.56.2

Starting Nmap 7.25BETA1 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-07-23 20:06 Pacific Daylight Time

Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.2
Host is up (0.00053s latency).
Not shown: 988 closed ports

PORT      STATE SERVICE
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
554/tcp   open  rtsp
1025/tcp  open  NFS-or-IIS
1026/tcp  open  LSA-or-nterm
1027/tcp  open  IIS
1028/tcp  open  unknown
1029/tcp  open  ms-lsa
2869/tcp  open  icslap
5357/tcp  open  wsdapi
10243/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 7.45 seconds
```

The output is the same for 127.0.0.1.

So I'm unsure why this happens, the nmap (or even ping for that matter) scans don't actually get to the Windows VM, but instead (I assume) some virtualbox network interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: disable the windows firewall and try again.